# How does the CDF come from the PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]Let $X_{n}$ be an sequence of random variables s.t. $f(x)=1$ if $x=2+\frac{1}{n}$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then the CDF is $F_{n}(x)=0$ if $x<2+\frac{1}{n}$ and $F_{n}(x)=1$ otherwise.

My question is how does the CDF come from the PDF

Anyone could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal B, \mu)$ where $\mu(\Omega) = 1$ the CDF (*cumulative* density function) is given by the PDF (*pointwise* density function) via the relation
$$F(x) = P(X\le x) = \int_{y\in\Omega, y\le x} f(y) \ \mathrm d\mu(y)$$
Where $F$ is the CDF and $f$ is the PDF. Your example doesn't constitute a correct example here for any $\mu$, because you relation PDF $\leftrightarrow$ CDF implies
$$\mu(\{2+\frac1n\}) = 1 \qquad\forall n$$
Contrary to $\mu(\Omega) = 1$.

---

A real example would be the space $([0,1], \mathcal B, \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure and $\mathcal B$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$. Pick $f(x) = 1$ as a PDF to obtain
$$F(x) = \int_0^x 1 \ \mathrm dx = x$$
as a CDF

---

If we do not require $(\Omega, \mathcal B, \mu)$ to be a probability space (i.e. $\mu(\Omega) = 1$), then we can take it as a measure space and obtain the same equality with the additional constraint $\int_\Omega f\ \mathrm d\mu = 1$ Your case would then work with an underlying measure space of $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B, \#)$ where $\#$ is the couting measure, $\#(A) = \text{number of elements in }A$. Then indeed
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \delta_{y, 2-\frac1n}\ \mathrm d\#(y) = \cases{1 & $2-\frac1n < x$ \\
0 & else}$$
As claimed. Note that the measure space has very bad properties, because $\#(A) = \infty$ for any set with nonempty interior. $\delta_{x,y} = \cases{1 & $x=y$\\0 & $x\ne y$}$ is the dirac delta, conveniently describing your PDF as $f(x) = \delta_{x,2-\frac1n}$.

Strictly spoken your course has a mistake here, not specifying this very odd space or claiming $\int f \mathrm d\lambda = 1$ (the usual integral, wich actually is $0$). In case you wonder what $\mathrm{Deg}(x)$ is, this is the degenerate distribution and the claim is *false* yet again because for the degenerate CDF,
$$\mathrm{Deg_2}(x) = P(2\le x) = \cases{1 & $x\ge 2$\\ 0  &$x<2$}$$
So there is a difference at the interesting point. In fact $F$ is not really a CDF for any random variable at all, since it would imply
$$P(X\le 2) = 0, P(X\le 2+\epsilon) = 1 \qquad\forall \epsilon > 0$$
But there is no real number $x$ such that $2< x\le 2+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, it shuold be $2+\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Jakoer That doesn't fix the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: But it's from the course note, I will upload the screen shot.

Comment: I might made mistakes somewhere, so I uploaded the screen shot of my note

Comment: @Jakoer Interestingly, your course notes seem not to require $\mu(\Omega) = 1$, so $\mu$ itself need not be a probability measure. I will add a section for that.

Comment: @Jakoer Please see if the new section clarifies what is wrong with your course notes.